# How can I tangle all org-babel blocks under the current org-heading?

Tags: org-babel

How can I tangle all source code blocks under the current org-heading?

Comment: So write one: `org-narrow-to-subtree` will do the narrowing, `org-tangle` will do the tangling and `widen` will get rid of the narrowing. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, NickD.

```
(defun org-tangle-org-heading ()
  (interactive)
  (org-narrow-to-subtree) 
  (org-babel-tangle)
  (widen)
)
```

Comment: `save-excursion` has nothing to do with preserving/restoring folding status - do `C-h f save-excursion` to read what it does. You are not changing the folding status by narrowing/widening the buffer.